# Slow SSH Connection while Internet Browsing

Tags: ssh, tunnel, ssh-tunnel

I have a macbook pro and I use SSH tunneling using terminal to bypass proxy. It is been a while that my browsing speed is so slow that showing google's homepage takes up to 10 secs. I wanted to know how I can fix this issue.
Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

Are you in an environment where you are not an admin (i.e. at work)? When you're not tunneling is your internet fast? If so, there may be a bandwidth limit on SSH ports for that internet connection.

If you are trying to access a fast connection via tunnel using a slow connection, it's no use -- that'd be like drinking from a small straw, then connecting a big straw to the end in the glass and expecting to be able to drink faster.

If you can be more specific I might be able to give a solution, but as it is now, there doesn't seem to be a whole lot you can do.